# show spaces between words

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

I write and compile in Overleaf (Latex). In Microsoft Word there is an option called "Show All", in order to see if there is more than 1 space between words. I would like to ask, if there is something similar in  Overleaf (Latex), in order to delete more space there that it should not be. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if there is, but why would you care? latex makes the same output whether you put 1 or 26 spaces between words in the source file.

Comment: please always include a complete small document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need nothing of that kind, because TeX is smarter than Word. Let's show it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

One two three four end.

One two  three   four    end.

\end{document}
```

With TeX any sequence of spaces (and tabs) is normalized to a single space.

[image]

Here's with “what you see is what you get”. No, thanks.

[image]

[image]

**Disclaimer.** My University has a site license for the dreaded suite of applications and, regrettably, some documents they send are only available through the said dreaded applications, which forces me to have a copy on my machine. A little advantage is being able to make some pictures like I did here.

Comment: I always suspected you were a secret Word user.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It took a couple of minutes to search for the way to show/hide the dots and ¶ symbols, until I found a small button to press.

Comment: Thanks, though when I delete some space, things look different...Maybe another reason...that I do not understand....

Comment: @dmtri An example would be needed. Note that spaces in the body of definitions are honored and endlines in the same may yield a space in output.

Comment: @egreg, if by definitions you do mean, Theorem envirement, (theorems, lemmas, examples, corollarry, etc), then that is the case. Thanks again.

Comment: @dmtri No, I mean `\newcommand{\macro}{text}` and similar.

Answer (score 3):

do you want this?

```tex
\verb*|i love  \LaTeX    yes!|
```

[image]